# why changing UIImageView content mode-affect its auto-layout in Xcode6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I am just lost with this auto-layout . Its really not stable, and every time it behaves differently.

I have a `UIImageView` , my only dream was that it will be in the size of the screen, for every device. Thats it,this is my dream .

I have the image view stretched on the view controller,created in `storyboard` .
I open the `storyboard` constrains, and i set the `"spacing to neighbour"` to be zero.  It than add 2 constrains to the image view . that means the spacing to the container view are 0 (!!) .

Than i set its background colour to be red, and i am not setting any image to it .

Running on devices in simulator, the red colour is not in the screen size, it covers part of the screen for every device i run .

Than , if you change the image content mode to `Aspect fit,or scaleToFill` , it change the red colour(u`iimageview`) size , so it then fit to the screen as accepted .
The content mode, as the name imply , is for the **content**, the image that INSIDE the view. why is this affecting my super simple view ?

There is something fundamental i am missing with this layouts thing .

Comment: Did you add the constraint with `Constrain to Margins` checkbox selected?

Comment: Well, i have the same misunderstanding on what is happening. When i change UIImageView content mode, imageView position and size CHANGES in superview. Not the content in UIImageView itself. That's a bit odd.

Comment: For those, who using IB, found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844128/auto-layout-keeps-stretching-uiimageview?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Ok , i got it, to anyone who is facing it,you better know that if you dont set an image to the UIImageView, Xcode6 is getting crazy , and do some unexpected things. When you set the image, it all goes to the right position.

Very unstable version .

Comment: ye same here, found a lot of weird behaviour