# Unexpected UIImageView Auto Layout Behavior - iOS 8

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout, storyboard

I've been trying to make a screen look like this:
[image]

But when i run it it keeps appearing like this:
[image]

So far I've tryed to debug the View Hierarchy but debugger shows the actual expected view:
[image]

I've come up with a workaround, putting the UIImageView before the top bar in the View Hierarchy so when it extends it goes under the top bar instead of on top.

**EDIT:**
The bottom white box is not a blank space, is actually a view intended to host 2 buttons.
My constraints are set as follow:

- Top banner:

  - height: 50
  - vertical spacing to Top Layout Guide: 0
  - leading and trailing spacing to superview: 0
- Image:

  - vertical spacing to Top banner: 0
  - leading and trailing spacing to superview: 0
- Bottom view (white box):

  - vertical spacing to Image: 0
  - leading and trailing spacing to superview: 0
  - proportional height to Image: 1:3

There are no other views in the hierarchy and no other constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found both the problem and the solution to this problem.
The `UIImageView` is actually behaving as expected, but the image it contains is spilling out of the view as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20848047/1952479).
The solution, explained in detail in the referenced answer, is as simple as to set `imageView.clipsToBounds = true`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place a `vertical spacing` between the top banner ("Amigo invesa app" written image) and the middle image (image with unknown green fruit/vegetable). But there is an unclear point, which is following

1. Exactly how many spacing do you want bottom of the middle image view

For example you want a 64px distance between middle image and the bottom of the view controller's view, then don't forget to put an `vertical spacing` with spacing 64px.

**According to your second editing::**
all the Constraint you have listed in the bottom. But there are some missing constraint which is

Height of the top banner, but you may want to resize the banner in bigger screen, that's why you need to specify other component's height (explicitly or implicitly). Here explicitly, I mean hard-coded specify the height of the middle image & the bottom white view's height & implicitly means by ratio between both of them as you mention `proportional height to Image: 1:3`. In the implicit case, you middle image height is not specified so the bottom white view's height can't be specified by the autolayout. Its an ambiguity situation for autolayout.

My advise will be please specify a explicit height for both top banner & bottom white view & remove the ratio constraint. That should do what you want.

Happy gui designing.

Comment: I already had that constraint. I'm sorry for not giving that information to begin with. Edited my question to include all details of the view hierarchy and constraints.

Comment: Oh my! I forgot to state the height constraint for the banner, It was already set up like that, and Auto Layout should be able to decide the height of the Image and the bottom view for them to fill all the remaining space.

Comment: please specify a height for the bottom white view & remove the proportion constraint as mentioned in the answer, then see what happens :)

Comment: Okay, just did that with a fixed height of 200 and got the same result. I think there is a bug with Auto Layout and UIImageView with contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill / .ScaleAspectFit